# Queue length of a service block in a bar chart

Tags: anylogic

I want to create a bar chart which contains the average of the amount of agents in the embedded queue of a service-block. I want to show the mean of agents while the simulation who are waiting in the queue.
What code I have to fill in the field: "Value:" in the bar chart properties?

Tank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataset (`noInQueue`) containing the `myQueue.size()` information and on the chart you need to type `noInQueue.getYMean()`.

Comment: If my service-block is named "service1" can I get the information about the queue length with the code "service1.size()" or is it another formulation?

Comment: Yes, you can access the number of agents inside that block with `service1.size()`

Comment: Exists a function to build the average of the amount like "getYMean" without values of zero?

Comment: Not that I know. When adding values to the dataset, you can choose not to add zeros.

Comment: How can I realize not to add zeros to the dataset? I think I must change the function "myQueue.size()", but how?